# Linked SQL Server and Update a Varchar(MAX) is truncated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a number of databases to maintain, and I don't want to create a script for each environment, so I created synonym in combination with a linked server to abstract away tables for my update statements.

My problem is that I can't seem to update a varchar(max) field with more than 24-32 characters (and it varies!)

I've been researching the web, and I can't find anything that directly speaks to this.  (UPDATE: Linking to my workstation, rather than to a server across the network, the local linked sql server updates fine.I think this is a environment issue on part of the host?  Perhaps some defined limit?)

Below is an example of how I have set things up.

```
--I create some dynamic sql to create the sysnonyms for me.
declare @Synonym varchar(30) = 'sym_Employee'
declare @DBTable = 'Employee'
Select @Stmt = 'create synonym ' + @Synonym + ' for TargetSQLServer.' + @DBName + '.dbo.' + @DBTable + ';'
exec @Stmt

--this statment stops at 24 chars, but the column def is varchar(max)
update sym_employee
set Notes = '012345678901234567890123456789'
where employee_ID = 1
```

Comment: Can't reproduce described behavoir on SQL-Server 2005 and SQL-Server 2008R2

Comment: The same problem is mentioned on SqlServerCentral, but there's no solution posted there: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1251727-391-1.aspx

Comment: 1) Does the Update statement work fine on the local (non-linked) database?

Comment: 2) Is there a trigger on that table?

Comment: 1) Yes it works fine on the non-linked db. I also have narrowed it down to the linked server, and not the synonym.
2) There is no trigger on the table

I'm thinking its a sp_serveroption in the same way rpc & rpc out is configured for stored procedures?

Comment: Confirmed that this is likely an environmental issue.  Script on Windows Server 2008R2 will trucate, but the same script running on a Win7/SQL Server 2008R2 and it works.... continuing to test

Comment: If you take '012345678901234567890123456789' and assign it to a VARCHAR(MAX) variable and set it using the variable, does the problem still occur?

Answer (score 0):

Have you played around with setting the `lazy schema validation` to `true` / `false`?

More details on the link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178532.aspx

Comment: It had no effect - but I had high hopes!

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that you have defined the length with varchar data type as when you not define length with varchar it takes default length (I guess 20 chars) that might be causing the problem.

Comment: I did this, but it had no effect - this problem still remains a mystery!